# Permissions in "All Site Content" Page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Is there a way to deny the access to the All Site Content" page in SharePoint 2007?
I know I can hide the lists and the link to the page, but users can still access via the URL

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can keep out anonymous users with the [ViewFormPagesLockDown](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2007/05/12/anonymous-users-forms-pages-and-the-lockdown-feature.aspx) feature.

But the best [suggestion](http://www.agileconcepts.com/Blogs/AQ/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=10) I've [seen](http://www.portlandsharepoint.org/Lists/General%20Discussion/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=/Lists/General%20Discussion/Hiding%20files%20from%20the%20_layouts%20directory&FolderCTID=0x01200200A9D7BBB78973A44490CABCEE9896BB69) for keeping out all users is to modify the web.config file:

```
<location path="_layouts/viewlsts.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```